# struggling to get cookie information to print in PHP

Tags: php, json, cookies

For some reason, I can't get the value of "price" from a cookie.

Here's the cookie info.

```
[{"label":"300 HOME ","price":150},{"label":"Yes, my phone line is (1234567890)","price":40},{"label":"internet 2","price":0},{"price":-25}]
```

And here's the code I'm using. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$cookie = $_COOKIE["MonthlyOptions"];
$obj = json_decode($cookie);
print $obj->{'price'}; 
?>
```

Comment: You have an array of items. Each item has a price property. Which item are you trying to get price from? See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f220a4097c504b8716197a0da60b136ec075a5e5

Comment: This one here. "label":"300 HOME ","price":150}

Comment: @JohnKBell Value you are trying to get is the property of the object which is the first element of the array, so it should be $obj[0]->price.

Comment: I tried the following but nothing gets printed... $cookie = $_COOKIE["MonthlyOptions"];
$obj = json_decode($cookie);
print $obj[0]->{'price'};

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both @waterloomatt and @Ravi Patel for their suggestions. In the end, what was stopping me from progressing was the need to add stripslashes.

```
$cookie = (stripslashes( $_COOKIE["MonthlyOptions"] ));
$obj = json_decode($cookie);
print $obj[0]->price;
```